How to make previous dates data from one tab appear in another tab
I am trying to create a function that pulls data from yesterday's date for "Skin Assessments"(B90:AE93), and "Pt Summary/Caregiver Updates"(B101:101)" from "November2024" tab and puts it into the "Updates" tab as the following:
November2024 tab "Skin Assessment"(B90:AE93)data for yesterdays date going to Updates tab "Yesterday's Skin Assessment"(B17:B20).
November2024 tab "Pt Summary/Caregiver Updates"(B101:101) data for yesterdays date going to Updates tab "Yesterday's Pt Summary/Caregiver Updates"(B12)
Here is the Google Sheets, editor enabled if you want to work it in there.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1adILT_xNvZY8RsbxfKx9hL74TOz-id8gaZKbrlo5C24/edit?usp=sharing

Consider providing input and expected output as plain text table in the question. Click here to create a table easily, which are easy to copy/paste.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question useless for others or images, which are hard to copy. Also, note that your email address can also be accessed by the public, if you share Google files.

In Updates tab:

For B11, use =INDEX(November2024!101:101, MATCH(Updates!B5 - 1, November2024!7:7, 0)).
For B17, use =ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(November2024!90:93, , MATCH(Updates!B5 - 1, November2024!7:7, 0)))

You should see something like this:

Explanation

November2024!B101:101 accesses others November2024's cells for row 101, starting from column B.
MATCH(Updates!B5 - 1, November2024!7:7, 0) finds the position of yesterday's date in November2024! row 7.
INDEX(November2024!101:101, ...) retrieves the value under that position in the row.
ARRAYFORMULA() retrieves the value under multiple rows.


You can review the Google Sheets function list to learn more.

Alternative Solution using apps script
I notice on the spreadsheet that you have shared that you are also considering using an app script to complete your project. Just to cover all bases and provide you as many options to complete your project I am sharing this alternate solution that will get your expected result using Google Apps Script.
Complete code:
function update() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var updates = ss.getSheetByName('Updates');
  var dataSrc = ss.getSheetByName('November2024');

  var today = new Date(new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0));
  updates.getRange('B5').setValue(today);
    
  var ystd = new Date(new Date(Date.now() - 864e5).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0));
  
  var dateRow = dataSrc.getRange(7, 1, 1, dataSrc.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  var colIndex = dateRow.flat().map(date => {
    var cellDate = new Date(new Date(date).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0));
    return cellDate.getTime();
  }).indexOf(ystd.getTime());

  var pt = dataSrc.getRange(90, colIndex + 1, 4, 1).getDisplayValues();
  var skin = dataSrc.getRange(101, colIndex + 1, 1, 1).getValues();

  updates.getRange(17, 2, 4, 1).setValues(pt);
  updates.getRange(11, 2, 1, 1).setValues(skin);
}

NOTE: You need to run the script at least once and accept the authorization.
Sample Output:

In order to automatically update your spreadsheet, it would be best for you to create an installable trigger instead of clicking the run button every time you want it to update (You can always choose what triggers best for your needs).
Here’s how to create a time-driven trigger for sample:

On the left side of your apps script, Go to Triggers
Add Triggers
Change the event source to Time-driven
Change the type of time based trigger to Day Timer
Specify the time of day you wanted it to update, then save.

Here’s the Trigger should look like:

References:

To create a Trigger
Map()
getValues()
setValues()

